Has Muhammad really waged many wars?
I find a deep discrepancy between the Holy Quran and the later histories of Muhammad ﷺ:
In the Quran, we find the words of guidance that our last Prophet received during the battle against the polytheists in Mecca in Sura At-Tawba, but there is no indication of any other war that he may have fought after that; the Suras that are said to have been revealed after that do not give any indication of any war activity.
In contrast, Islamic traditions mention many (25 to 29, see here) battles, suggesting that he never stopped waging wars after this. None of these battles seem to have been recorded outside Islam. I suspect that the hadiths reporting Muhammad's exuberant war activities were invented by later Islamic leaders who successfully conquered many regions to justify their actions.
Are there any authors who support my suspicion, based on the Qur'an, that Muhammad was much less belligerent and much more inclined to peace than the traditions suggest?

This question has several fallacies.

The war with the pagans at Mecca was not just a single battle, there were several battles and skirmishes before Mecca was conquered. The Quran explicitly mentions some of these such as Badr, Uhad, Ahzab etc.

The number 25-29 is the total number of expeditions which the Prophet ﵆  led in person. Most of these were before the conquest of Mecca and a few were after it. Also as the linked answers state there were several expeditions where he did not participate in person but appointed someone else as the commander of an army.

There were battles with other groups apart from the people of Mecca such as other pagan tribes and the Jews. The Quran mentions for example Ahzab, Khaybar, Banu Nadir, Banu Qurayzah etc.

Surah at-Tawbah was revealed after the conquest of Mecca, or at least most of its verses were revealed after it. So it does not deal with the battle(s) that were fought against them but with those who were fought afterwards. See Time of the revelation of verse 9:5

The Quran itself mentions many battles, and also mentions some battles after the conquest of Mecca such as the Battle of Hunayn and the Expedition to Tabuk:

لقد نصركم الله في مواطن كثيرة ويوم حنين
Allah has already given you victory in many regions and [even] on the day of Hunayn
— Quran 9:25


أولا يرون أنهم يفتنون في كل عام مرة أو مرتين
Do they not see that they are tried every year once or twice
— Quran 9:126 - exegetes mention that the trials every year include battles



So, depending on how you define 'many' there is no basis to dispute that the Prophet ﵆ fought many battles. Nor is there any basis to suspect that he did not fight any war after the polytheists in Mecca.
